# What's the meaning of 'For justice speaks thus to me'?

Tags: meaning

This excerpt is from Nietzsche's book, 'Thus Spoke Zrathustra':

> I do not want to be confused with these preachers of equality, nor
> taken for one of them. **For justice speaks thus to me**: 'Men are not
> equal.' And they should not become so, either! For what were my love
> of the Superman if I spoke otherwise?

I don't have any clue what's the meaning of the sentence, 'For justice speaks thus to me'.

The book link [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=a9VxKgui0mEC&pg=PT168&lpg=PT168&dq=For%20justice%20speaks%20to%20me:%20men%20are%20not%20equal.%20And%20they%20should%20not%20become%20so%20either!&source=bl&ots=3v_wHEy6Sy&sig=ACfU3U3LRmt0O_w6_eScaP6c_k43q3XuJw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj15vK_5J7qAhVLbc0KHeGhAOkQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=For%20justice%20speaks%20to%20me%3A%20men%20are%20not%20equal.%20And%20they%20should%20not%20become%20so%20either!&f=false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your are reading Nietzsche.  This is not going to be easy.

There a metaphor, but not a special meaning here.

> For (meaning "because") justice ("justice" is personified, we treat the concept of justice like a person)  speaks thus (in this way) to me.

And then Nietzsche goes on to tell us the way that "justice" speaks to him: "Men are not all equal".  etc

There is no very special use of English here, just Nietzsche

Comment: Agreed. Nietzsche attributes his own opinion to a personified “Justice” so as to give it false authority. All he is saying is “I disagree”.

Comment: Yes, but this is not "Philosophy" stack exchange.